# How to interpret Tensorboard Histograms

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorboard

I am new to Tensorflow. I was wondering if someone could guide me as to how to interpret the Tensorflow histograms. The following are the histograms for the network prediction and filters at the first layer. W_conv1 is of the shape[5 5 3 10]. How can I view each filter individually? [image: This is the histograms for graph's prediction]

[image: This is the histogram for one of the weights of one of the constitutional layers]

Comment: possibly duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42315202/understanding-tensorboard-weight-histograms