# Tensorboard - Splitting a fully connected layer into 2 histograms for vizualization

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am aware that I can visualize the weights of the layers in a histogram using tensorboard [Understanding TensorBoard (weight) histograms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42315202/understanding-tensorboard-weight-histograms)

My question, is it possible to "split" a fully connected layer into two separate histograms ? Because I have input coming from 2 sources that is concatenated before before going through a fully connected layer and I want to see the weight distribution for the 2 sources. Below I have a simple example where `a` and `b` are concatenated before being passed through a fully connected layer.

a is of size 1024 and b of size 256. The out layer has 1024 units.

```
out = tf.matmul(tf.concat(values=(a, b), axis=1), weight) + bias
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `weight` to have shape `1280 x 1024`, you can first [split](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/array_ops/slicing_and_joining) your `weight` as

```
weight_a = tf.slice(weight, [0, 0], [1024, 1024])
weight_b = tf.slice(weight, [1024, 0], [1280, 1024])
```

Now, you can visualize `weight_a` and `weight_b`.

The slicing can be generalized as well but since you explicitly specified the size of each tensor, the above is the quickest method.

Comment: yes you are right. that is simple yet effective enough