# How to debug the result from SSD-InceptionV2 in Tensorflow object detection API?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning

Instead of fine tuning multiple hyper-parameters,

is there any approach/method to analyze the following condition:

I use the pre-trained SSD-InceptionV2 from Google model zoo, and train with KITTI dataset for vehicle detection.

However, I wonder why the trained model cannot detect any vehicle in the 1st image but two vehicles in the 2nd image.

For example, is it caused by the scales/aspect ratios of default boxes or from feature extractor?

[image]
[image]

========== Edit ==========

For debugging, I mean

either

[show the weight histogram in this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42315202/understanding-tensorboard-weight-histograms?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

or

in [Visualizing and Understanding Convolutional Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.2901.pdf)

you can visualize the higher level layers like

[image]

Thank you for precious time on my question.