# How to plot multi-epoch x-y line graph in Tensorboard, which is not a histogram?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, tensorboard, pytorch-lightning

I want to plot a standard line graph in tensorboard - per epoch.

In Matplotlib I would just use `plt.plot(np.arange(100), np.arange(100))` [and not `plt.hist()`], but would be left with multiple graphs, instead of [the convenient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42315202/understanding-tensorboard-weight-histograms) tensorboard UI.

I want such a graph to be generated every epoch, and be plotted near each other, to have the output look similar to that of `histogram`, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42315202/understanding-tensorboard-weight-histograms), but display data as it- just plot it in the relevant epoch.

I would use the histogram mechanism, but I don't know how to use it to just plot values rather than histograms (which distort the X-axis, and count on the Y-axis, instead of just displaying the data as-is).

---

I am using Pytorch [and Pytorch lightning], so a compatible solution will be preferred.